# How to see if particle system is a hair system, with Python

Tags: python, particles

Currently,I have this code that checks to see if the active object has a particle system.

```
import bpy
if bpy.context.object.particle_systems:
    print("There is a psystem!")
else:
    print("No psystem!")
```

This works. How can I make it print true only if there is a particle system AND that particle system is a hair system?

Comment: That code checks for uv layers not particle systems.

Comment: Edited the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below gives a list of all hair particle systems on the context object.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
obj = context.active_object

hair_particle_systems = [ps for ps in obj.particle_systems 
                            if ps.settings.type == 'HAIR']
if len(hair_particle_systems):
    print("%s has %d HAIR particle systems" % 
             (obj.name, len(hair_particle_systems)))
```

Comment: Edited code, what I have works already. I just need to know how to make it search for particle systems and if particle system is hair.